# Count ID in sql query

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following data,

```
id    emp_id   csa_taken
1      100       2
2      100       2
3      100       0
4      100       2

5      101       2
6      101       2
7      101       0
8      101       0
```

---

I expect a result with count where csa_taken=2 for individual employee.

expected result:

```
emp_id   count_csa_taken
  100       3
  101       2
```

I have tried the following query with a failed attempt.

---

```
Select count(employee_id)  From $employeeCSA  where csa_taken=2
```

Please suggest as I am new to sql.

Comment: Please include the exact expected result in your query. The explanation of the rules is not clear to me.

Comment: you need a `group by emp_id` in your query

Comment: @Bhagwa Dhari: If one of the answers helped you, don't forget to accept it as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly you like to count all employees with a `cas_taken` of two. As there are multiple entries for the `csa_taken` for one employee you need to group them.

E.g.:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM $employeeCSA WHERE csa_taken = 2 GROUP_BY employee_id
```

Please note that `COUNT(*)` counts the rows (not the fields).

Answer (score 1):

You also need group by. Try like:

```
Select count(employee_id),emp_id  From $employeeCSA  where csa_taken=2 
group by emp_id
```

Answer (score 1):

If i understand correctly, then you can try this:

```
SELECT emp_id,COUNT(emp_id) from dbo.Sample WHERE csa_token = 2 GROUP BY emp_id
```